# Android: Can I set converted view layout in getView()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm setting different height for my custom listview items based on screen orientation, and as in code below I listen to screen orientation changes, and set a global value according to it, and when getView(...) gets called on listview items I set the height of the converted view.

**My question is, is there a better solution than this?**

**How bad this approach affect the UI loading speed process?**

I'm targeting API14+

P.S: (200 & 300) below are added here as example, they are not fixed at runtime, they are changed during runtime according to screen dpi.

```
int mConvertViewHeight;


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        mConvertViewHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        mConvertViewHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 300, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

In my listview custom array adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int aConvertViewPosition, View aConvertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
        mParams = aConvertView.getLayoutParams();
        mParams.height = mMainActivity.mConvertViewHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need just different item view in portrait/landscape mode, you can create different layouts in layout-land and layout-port folders

Comment: That's a good solution but numbers above (200 & 300) are not fixed, I added them here as example, these numbers change according to screen dpi. Any other suggestion? away from creating different folders layouts for different dpi, as sw<200>layout and so on.

Comment: Any more suggestions ?